# How to make a class(SwitchBoard) which change the switches' on and off?

Tags: python, function, class, boolean

I wand to build a class SwitchBoard with the following properties:

• When I create a switchboard, I should be able to set the number of switches it      contains.

• All switches should start in the "off" position.

• If I print a switchboard, it should print something along the lines of: "The following switches are
on: 0 2 4 6 8".

• The which switch method should return a list of integers representing the switches that are on, in
order(e.g., [1,3,5,7,9]).

• If I call flip(n) with n as an integer, it should flip the state of the n’th lightswitch.

• If I call flip every(n) with n as an integer, it should flip the state of every n’th lightswitch, starting
at 0. So flip every(2) would flip switches 0, 2, 4, 6, etc.

• The method reset(), should turn all switches off.

• If I ask the switchboard to flip a switch which doesn’t exist, nothing should happen (it shouldn’t crash)

So, I first build a Lightswitch which works well.

```
class LightSwitch():
''' A class to reprenset a general light switch'''

    def __init__(self, light_state):
        if(light_state == 'on'):
            mode = True
        else:
            mode = False
        self._state = mode

    def __str__(self):
        if(self._state == True):
           return 'I am on'
        if(self._state == False):
            return 'I am off'

    def turn_on(self):
        if(self._state == False):
            self._state = not self._state

    def turn_off(self):
        if(self._state == True):
            self._state = not self._state

    def flip(self):
        self._state = not self._state
```

And for SwitchBoard, that is what i got so gar.

```
class SwitchBoard():

    def __init__(self, num_switch):
        self.switches = []
        for i in range(num_switch):
            self.switches.append(LightSwitch('off'))

    def __str__(self):
        switch_on = ''
        switch_on_list = self.which_switch()
        for i in range(0, len(switch_on_list)):
            switch_on += ' ' + str(switch_on_list[i])
        return 'The following switches are on:' + switch_on

    def which_switch(self):
        switch_on_list = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.switches) - 1):
            if(self.switches[i] == True):
                switch_on_list.append(i)
        return switch_on_list

    def flip(self, switch_index):
        if(switch_index <= len(self.switches) -1 ):
        self.switches[switch_index].flip()

    def flip_every(self, step):
        for i in range(0,len(self.switches), step):
            self.flip(i)        

    def reset(self):
        for every_switch in self.switches:
            every_switch.turn_off()


if(__name__==("__main__")):
s = SwitchBoard(10)
s.flip(2)
print(s)
print(s.which_switch())
s.flip_every(2)
print(s)
print(s.which_switch())
```

This isn't working out. The flip just seems not working and i dont know why.
Please help!

Comment: in which_switch function, you miss it : not if(self.switches[i] == True): but if(self.switches[i]._state == True):

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't delete your questions after receiving a satisfactory answer. It is cheating the rest of the world which might benefit from it, and the answerers.

Answer (score 10):

Try with

```
def which_switch(self):
    switch_on_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(self.switches) - 1):
        if(self.switches[i]._state == True):
            switch_on_list.append(i)
    return switch_on_list
```

But indeed, you should add a getter to your **LightSwitch**, and use this getter, because access an underscored variable is not very clean...
For example, you can add:

```
is_on(self):
    return self._state
```

and use it like this:

```
if(self.switches[i].is_on()):
```

But, great code, just a little miss.

By the way, you have some other mistake :

```
if(switch_index <= len(self.switches) -1 ):
```

is not clean, because you never forbid negative number for example.

Comment: I agree.. was just about to post the same.  Some of these for..range() loops have problems.. it is better in most cases to iterate over a python list using an iterator eg `for switch in list_of_switches:` .. much less error-prone